# How do I hide a sheet with a button in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a button to hide the sheet. Ideally, it would hide the sheet where the button is located.

To be simple, sheet 1 has a form to fill out. The typical name, address, phone number, etc. Sheet 2 and 3 also have the same fields that is going to be referenced to the 'Data' tab as well. On a sheet named 'Data', I will add fields that will populate simply with the = option like (=Data!...)

However, I do not want the Data page in view once the information is added. We all know the simple right click and hide sheet. But sometimes that's too much for some people that will use this sheet and a pretty button would work better.

I was successful using:
Module 1

```
Sub SheetCommand()
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value <> vbNullString Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
Else
Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Sheet1 Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address <> "$C$2" Then Exit Sub
Run "SheetCommand"
End Sub
```

However, I am not very VB savvy and have hit a dead end. Could someone help show me how to apply this to a button? I don't want it to reference the $C$2 field as noted on the example, but just when someone presses the button, the sheet goes away. I'm not worried about getting it back as someone can be ready to get it the old fashioned way. This would help the data entry process for this manual form so much easier.

---

Edit: basically, I need help creating a vba code where I can hide the page. I'd like to create a button where once clicked, it hides that page. I showed an example of a code where I got it to work but it only works if that cell is populated. How do I make it work on button click?

---

I found this code that does what I need but I would like to tell it a specific Sheet Name instead of having to type it in B6 and B7.

```
Sub ShowHideWorksheets()
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("B6:B7")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Cell.Value).Visible = Not
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Cell.Value).Visible
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Insert button, right click, assign macro to it?

Comment: The setup you've described doesn't lend itself to longevity.  If this forms keeps getting used for months or years, the number of hidden sheets and the number of references to those hidden sheets will increase to an enormous number, potentially slowing down the workbook considerably, and absolutely making it very unwieldy for anyone working on the sheet, especially if it ever needs updates/changes.  Why not just have users enter their data on a new row of the Data sheet directly?

Comment: @tigeravatar some users will make you cry when they destroy the sheet. But you make a good point. OP should just keep `data` sheet hidden and instead have button send whatever was entered on sheet 1 onto last row+1 of `data`

Comment: It's a template workbook. It is filled out, saved, emailed, and the template is used again. I fill out the excel form with one customer's information and that file isn't used again.

Comment: I found a code that some what works. How can I make this code say a sheet name only instead of it being keyed onto B6 and B7? Sub ShowHideWorksheets()
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("B6:B7")
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Cell.Value).Visible = Not ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Cell.Value).Visible
Next Cell
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not very clear to me what's your exact goal

for instance, assuming "Sheet 2" and "Sheet2" would point to the same sheet, in your question you seem to reference it as being both a "Form" sheet (*"...sheet 1 has a form to fill out....**Sheet 2** and 3 also have the same fields..."*) and "Data" sheet (`Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = False`)

so here follow some *possible* solutions:

1) you want to hide "Data" sheet before closing the workbook it's contained in

then place the following code in "ThisWorkbook" code pane of the workbook containing "Data" sheet

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Visible = False
End Sub
```

2) you want to hide "Data" sheet once some cells have been filled up in ANY sheet other than "Data"

then place the following code in "ThisWorkbook" code pane of the workbook containing "Data" sheet

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name <> "Data" Then
        With Sh
            'here follows code to check if "the information is added"
            'for instance:
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A2:C2")) = .Range("A2:C2").Count Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Visible = False 'check if all cells in range "A2" to "C2" has been filled with some data
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

3) you want to hide "Data" sheet once some cells have been filled up in ALL sheets other than "Data"

then place the following code in "ThisWorkbook" code pane of the workbook containing "Data" sheet

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim hideBool As Boolean: hideBool = True 'set initial value as true

    If Sh.Name <> "Data" Then
        For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            With Sh
                'here follows code to check if "the information is added"
                'for instance:
                hideBool = hideBool And WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A2:C2")) = .Range("A2:C2").Count ''check if all cells in range "A2" to "C2" of current sheet has been filled with some data
            End With
            If Not hideBool Then Exit For
        Next sht
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Visible = Not hideBool ' hide if ALL sheets met "information is added" condition
    End If
End Sub
```

4) otherwise give more info about the desired behavior

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to fill out the response. I am the worst to explain my thoughts. What I think might be clear, is often confusing for others. I'll try to explain it better. I use Excel to fill out a form that is later emailed to another person. I plan on creating a 4th Sheet within the document that will autopopulate fields in the other three sheets. For example, I create a work order number and put it on all three sheets. My solution is to create a 4th sheet that a user can type in the information that will fill in the rest of those fields. So if I make WO12345, it is on all 3

Comment: However, once they fill in this 4th sheet, I wanted to create a button that can hide the sheet. All the information will be there, just hidden. Because once it is sent to the next person, they may be confused about this 4th sheet and could cause a work flow problem. The people filling out the 4th sheet aren't excel savvy and right click and hide sheet is too much...... So a solution was the button that could hide it once they filled it in.